# Team Services control options in Release task

Tags: azure-devops

I might be doing something wrong, but I have created a Build and a Release in VSTS. For the release I need to execute a task only if one of the previous failed. This is easy for the tasks in the Build, there is a dropdown with several options including "Only when a previous task has failed", however for the release, I only have Always run and continue on error, which doesn't work for me.

Is this because the control options for release doesn't support the same options as the build or is something missing for my VSTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task conditions aren't yet an option for tasks used in releases.